# How can I add new items to a selection text menu?

Tags: flutter, menu

How can I add new items to the selection text popup menu (such as  `Copy/Paste/Cut/item2`)
in a Flutter custom text selection menu

Comment: please give more brief

Comment: When u selection text  appear selection menu  items  such as  Copy or paste  or cut  l wante add new items and new action

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it, but there is a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu) that helps out with it. This [article](https://medium.com/@retroportalstudio/focused-pop-up-menu-in-flutter-15766d0ab414) talks about the creation of the package. But if you use the package (which I would recommend) just wrap the widget you want to have this functionality with in a `FocusedMenuHolder`. The Readme contains the following example:

```
 Expanded(
                child: GridView(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                  children: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

                       // Wrap each item (Card) with Focused Menu Holder
                      .map((e) => FocusedMenuHolder(
                        menuWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.50,
                        blurSize: 5.0,
                        menuItemExtent: 45,
                        menuBoxDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey,borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                        animateMenuItems: true,
                        blurBackgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                        menuOffset: 10.0, // Offset value to show menuItem from the selected item
                        bottomOffsetHeight: 80.0, // Offset height to consider, for showing the menu item ( for example bottom navigation bar), so that the popup menu will be shown on top of selected item.
                        menuItems: <FocusedMenuItem>[
                          // Add Each FocusedMenuItem  for Menu Options
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Open"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.open_in_new) ,onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ScreenTwo()));
                          }),
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Favorite"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border) ,onPressed: (){}),
                          FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Delete",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.redAccent,) ,onPressed: (){}),
                        ],
                        onPressed: (){},
                        child: Card(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Image.asset("assets/images/image_$e.jpg"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                      ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectionControls` parameter to customize text selection menu:

```dart
TextField(selectionControls: MyMaterialTextSelectionControls()),
```

and implement delegate class like here:

```dart
class MyMaterialTextSelectionControls extends MaterialTextSelectionControls {
  // Padding between the toolbar and the anchor.
  static const double _kToolbarContentDistanceBelow = 10.0;
  static const double _kToolbarContentDistance = 8.0;

  /// Builder for material-style copy/paste text selection toolbar.
  @override
  Widget buildToolbar(
    BuildContext context,
    Rect globalEditableRegion,
    double textLineHeight,
    Offset selectionMidpoint,
    List<TextSelectionPoint> endpoints,
    TextSelectionDelegate delegate,
    ClipboardStatusNotifier clipboardStatus,
    Offset? lastSecondaryTapDownPosition,
  ) {
    final TextSelectionPoint startTextSelectionPoint = endpoints[0];
    final TextSelectionPoint endTextSelectionPoint =
        endpoints.length > 1 ? endpoints[1] : endpoints[0];
    final Offset anchorAbove = Offset(
      globalEditableRegion.left + selectionMidpoint.dx,
      globalEditableRegion.top +
          startTextSelectionPoint.point.dy -
          textLineHeight -
          _kToolbarContentDistance,
    );
    final Offset anchorBelow = Offset(
      globalEditableRegion.left + selectionMidpoint.dx,
      globalEditableRegion.top +
          endTextSelectionPoint.point.dy +
          _kToolbarContentDistanceBelow,
    );
    final value = delegate.textEditingValue;
    return MyTextSelectionToolbar(
      anchorAbove: anchorAbove,
      anchorBelow: anchorBelow,
      clipboardStatus: clipboardStatus,
      handleCustomButton: () {
        print(value.selection.textInside(value.text));
        delegate.hideToolbar();
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyTextSelectionToolbar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextSelectionToolbar({
    Key? key,
    required this.anchorAbove,
    required this.anchorBelow,
    required this.clipboardStatus,
    required this.handleCustomButton,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Offset anchorAbove;
  final Offset anchorBelow;
  final ClipboardStatusNotifier clipboardStatus;
  final VoidCallback? handleCustomButton;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));

    final List<_TextSelectionToolbarItemData> items =
        <_TextSelectionToolbarItemData>[
      _TextSelectionToolbarItemData(
        onPressed: handleCustomButton ?? () {},
        label: 'Custom button',
      ),
    ];

    int childIndex = 0;
    return TextSelectionToolbar(
      anchorAbove: anchorAbove,
      anchorBelow: anchorBelow,
      toolbarBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) =>
          Container(color: Colors.pink, child: child),
      children: items
          .map((_TextSelectionToolbarItemData itemData) =>
              TextSelectionToolbarTextButton(
                padding: TextSelectionToolbarTextButton.getPadding(
                    childIndex++, items.length),
                onPressed: itemData.onPressed,
                child: Text(itemData.label),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class _TextSelectionToolbarItemData {
  const _TextSelectionToolbarItemData({
    required this.label,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final String label;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
}
```

Or checkout this one [text_selection_controls](https://pub.dev/packages/text_selection_controls)

Comment: Expanded my answer